# Docker create images "Ubuntu 14.04" with Docker file

Tags: docker

I want to create images with dockerfile, can be assisted to install Ubuntu 14:04 with dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply start your Dockerfile with:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

You can then add anything you need on top of that base image.

Comment: Not like this to make the image ubuntu 14:04 on Docker? https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/3c355946fd5164da3f31063a5c5f249c826f7071/trusty/Dockerfile

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto You don't need that: it is already alvailable, pre-made for you, on Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/)

Comment: itu untuk membuat images Ubuntu 14.04 dengan dockerfile?

Comment: @Yang akan menggunakan gambar ubuntu, dan Anda dapat menambahkan file tambahan untuk gambar yang, membangun citra Anda sendiri berdasarkan ubuntu 14.04. Tidak perlu untuk membangun kembali ubuntu itu sendiri, hanya menambahkan apa yang Anda ingin menginstal dalam ubuntu dibuat untuk Anda.

Comment: Berarti saya bisa menginstall aplikasi dalam OS yang ada pada images ubuntu yang ada pada docker?

Comment: @
Jika Anda menggunakan `FROM ubuntu:14.04`, Anda dapat menambahkan aplikasi lain dalam gambar ubuntu. Tapi cek dulu Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/): beberapa aplikasi yang akan segera melangsungkan pesta di sana, dibangun di atas ubuntu (atau distro Linux lainnya) sudah. Lihat misalnya Nginx: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/08eeb0e3f0a5ee40cbc2bc01f0004c2aa5b78c15/Dockerfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96522/discussion-between-yudi-dwiyanto-and-vonc).

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto 
Saya tidak dapat mengakses chatting di tempat kerja. Anda dapat mengajukan pertanyaan baru dengan rincian lebih lanjut tentang apa yang Anda coba lakukan.

Comment: Tadi saya mencoba menambahkan :

COPY /home/sts/erp-enterprise /home/sts/ 
pada dockerfile namun error, seperti ini errornya 
Step 2 : COPY /home/sts/erp-enterprise /home/sts/ 
lstat home/sts/erp-enterprise: no such file or directory

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Itu adalah pertanyaan yang berbeda. Meminta yang baru (dengan link kembali ke satu ini untuk menjelaskan konteks)